# Openlayers - coordinates saving after drag cause point go to 0,0

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a map with a dragable point and after drag, I update latitude and longitude fields in the form. But when I do that like this:

```
drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors, {
  autoActivate: true,
  onComplete: function() {
    $('#place_latitude').val(point.transform(mapp, wgs84).y);
    return $('#place_longitude').val(point.transform(mapp, wgs84).x);
  }
});
```

After attempt to make second drag (from one point to another) point goes to 0,0. Without `onComplete` everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are transforming the `point` two times... `transform` method modifies `point` itself, it doesn't create new object.

You may use `point.clone()` instead of `point`.